# Проверка входных данных Python 3.x

Tags: python

На вход программе пользователь вводит данные в WKT-подобном формате, происходит проверка входных данных и дальше вытаскиваются данные и передаются в экземпляр класса для вычисления площади и периметра фигуры.

Пример входных данных:

```
circle(0 0, 1.5)
triangle((-3 -2, -1 0, -3 2, -3 -2))
```

Пример ошибки:

```
circlee(1 2, 3)
^
Error: expected 'circle'

circle(1 2, 3(
             ^
Error: expected ')'

circle(1 2, 3) 123
               ^
Error: unexpected token

circle(x1 2, 3.0)
       ^
Error: expected number

trianggle((-3 -2, -1 0, -3 2, -3 -2))
      ^
Error: expected 'triangle'

trianggle((-x3 -2, -1 0, -3 2, -3 -2))
            ^
Error: expected number
```

Пример правильного ввода:

```
circle(1 2, 3)

triangle((-3 -2, -1 0, -3 2, -3 -2))
```

Мой код:

```py
def input_validation():
       while True:
        input_data = input('Enter a data: ')
        words = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', input_data.lower())
        numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', input_data)
        numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers]
        if words != ['c', 'i', 'r', 'c', 'l', 'e']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        elif words[0] != ['c']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        elif words[1] != ['i']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        elif words[2] != ['r']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        elif words[3] != ['c']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        elif words[4] != ['l']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        elif words[5] != ['e']:
            print(f'Error: expected "Circle"')
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Не могу понять как реализовать проверку входных данных

Comment: Используйте **регулярные выражения**. Конкретная реализация будет зависеть от того, какие виды ввода у вас возможны.

Comment: @CrazyElf совет звучит примерно как "используйте компьютер" ;-)

Comment: @Kromster Так до вашего исправления автор просил совет, а не конкретное решение ;)

Comment: Сформулируйте для себя А - что такое "корректность" в вашем конкретном случае. Б - подумайте как вы будете разбирать корректные входные данные.

Comment: А так и есть. Потому как непонятно что ТС написал. В одном месте "circle", в другом "circlee". Что после этого можно советовать?

Comment: @CrazyElf так я и иронизирую, что совет уж очень общий. На регулярках все равно придется логику проверки как-то реализовывать )

Comment: @passant Так это он пример ошибки привёл. Но всё-равно непонятно, какие ещё варианты ввода есть.

Comment: @CrazyElf -  точно. Очень специфически сформулирован вопрос. Может тогда сразу сделать грамматический разбор с описанием грамматики языка предложить? :-)

Comment: Данные пользователь вводит через консоль, корректный ввод figure_name(x y, r) пример circle(1 1, 3), нужно отловить не правильное написание названия фигуры, и в скобках чтобы не было всякой ереси понаписано, я вот не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: @Goganchikk Вот и добавьте всё это в вопрос. И напишите список возможных фигур. Хотя по-хорошему у разных фигур может ведь быть разное количество параметров, между прочим.

Comment: Можно открыть вопрос?

Comment: @Goganchikk Можно, но кроме `circle` не хотите варианты фигур ещё привести, чтобы вопрос был более полным? Просто список что там ещё может быть, а то потом у вас будет обязательно вопрос, а как не только на `circle` сразу проверить

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил еще один вариант фигуры для полноты вопроса

Comment: @Goganchikk Ждите, как голоса наберутся, вопрос переоткроют. Но, повторюсь - смотрите в сторону **регулярных выражений**, рано или поздно вам их придётся изучить и эта задача хороший вариант для их изучения и применения.

Comment: @CrazyElf "рано или поздно вам их придётся изучить" - "Единственное, что вызывало у меня опасение — это регулярки. Ничто в мире не бывает более беспомощным, безответственным и порочным, чем регулярные выражения. Я знал, что рано или поздно мы перейдем и на эту дрянь."

Comment: @Goganchikk посмотрите библиотеку FuzzyWuzzy, она позволяет сравнивать текст с нечетким совпадением.